# Parser file using Linux Shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file in format like this:

```
method1|duration=300s
method2|duration=300s
method1|duration=500s
method1|duration=300s
method1|duration=700s
method3|duration=300s
...
```

How can I get the average duration time of method1 using Linux Shell?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
awk -F'[=s]' '/method1/{t+=$2;c++}END{printf "%ss\n",t/c}' file
```

`-F[=s]` sets the field delimiter to `=` or `s` making it easy to extract the numerical value between them. `t+=$2` will add the numerical value to the total `t`. `c++` will count the lines containing the term `method1`. After the last line of input has been processed `END`, we print the total `t` divided by `c`, the number of lines containing `method1`.

Note: Initialization of the variables `c` and `t` is not necessary since awk initializes them with `0` on their first usage.

Comment: would be good if you add a selection on method1 (required in the question) and average on this only:


    awk -F'[=s]' '/method1/{s+=$2;count+=1}END{print s/count}'

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do it as:

```
awk -F '[=s]' 'BEGIN{count=0;sum=0} /method1/{sum+=$2;count+=1} END{print sum/count}' filename
```

All the duration must be of same time unit.

This will initially set `count` to `0` and `sum` to `0`. During each iteration, `sum` will get added and `count` will be incremented if `method1` is found in the line. At the end, `sum/count` will be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for that. If duration is always in seconds something like this should work:

```
awk -F '\\||=' 'BEGIN { sum = 0; rows = 0 } { if ($1 == "method1") { sum += $3; rows += 1; } } END { print sum / rows "s" }' data_file
```